# Solr 3.6.1 - PatternReplaceFilterFactory not working with wildcard search

Tags: solr, pattern-matching, solr-schema

PatternReplaceFilterFactory not working with wildcard search.

**Example:**

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
```

Search with **q=defaultsearch:*ab12cd***, expected to give the result for the word ***abcd*** but it is not working.

Can you please suggest me, is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers mentions -

> On wildcard and fuzzy searches, no text analysis is performed on the
>   search word.

So the search query will not undergo any analysis during query time.
Hence the pattern replace filter will not be applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any possibility to have this functionality in further release of Solr ?

Comment: I suppose there is jira to have wildcard queries go through analysis. you may need to check the jiras. Am not sure how it would work in your case if your query goes through the pattern filter the * would be removed and it may not be a wildcard query anymore.